# Getting a list of values from a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, 
 {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3} , 
 {'value': 'cars', 'blah': 4}]
```

I want `['apple', 'banana', 'cars']`

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 529, accepted):

Assuming every dict has a `value` key, you can write (assuming your list is named `l`)

```
[d['value'] for d in l]
```

If `value` might be missing, you can use

```
[d['value'] for d in l if 'value' in d]
```

Comment: To treat missing value for a key, one may also use d.get("key_to_lookup", "alternate_value"). Then, it will look like: [d.get('value', 'alt') for d in l] . If value is not present as key, it will simply return 'alt'.

Comment: This "magic" is known as list comprehension https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Life Saver! I have been trying/searching this for sqlalchemy objects since long. Now it worked like ```[d.value for d in l]``` thank you :)

Comment: It'll be `d['Value']` instead of `d['value']`.

Answer (score 61):

Here's another way to do it using map() and lambda functions:

```
>>> map(lambda d: d['value'], l)
```

where l is the list.
I see this way "sexiest", but I would do it using the list comprehension.

Update:
In case that 'value' might be missing as a key use:

```
>>> map(lambda d: d.get('value', 'default value'), l)
```

Update: I'm also not a big fan of lambdas, I prefer to name things... this is how I would do it with that in mind:

```
>>> import operator
>>> get_value = operator.itemgetter('value')
>>> map(get_value, l)
```

I would even go further and create a sole function that explicitly says what I want to achieve:

```
>>> import operator, functools
>>> get_value = operator.itemgetter('value')
>>> get_values = functools.partial(map, get_value)
>>> get_values(l)
... [<list of values>]
```

With Python 3, since `map` returns an iterator, use `list` to return a list, e.g. `list(map(operator.itemgetter('value'), l))`.

Comment: The list comprehension makes a lot more sense here.

Comment: If you're going to use the first `map`, use `operator.itemgetter('value')`, not a `lambda`.

Answer (score 26):

```
[x['value'] for x in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: or [d.getkey('value') for d in dict_list]

Comment: @rpInt Um, there is no such thing as `getkey`.. do you mean `d.get('value')`? That would be the same as @isbadawi's 2nd list comprehension, not Michal's.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant get. And I meant it as something that won't throw exception if key is missing. But @isbadawi's solution is better as get() will supply None (or whatever we specify as default) when the key is missing.

Answer (score 8):

Using list comprehension

**input:**

```
d = [{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3}, {'value': 'cars', 'blah': 4}]
    
        
values = [i['value'] for i in d]

print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cars']
```

Answer (score 7):

I think as simple as below would give you what you are looking for.

```
In[5]: ll = [{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3} , {'value': 'cars', 'blah':4}]
In[6]: ld = [d.get('value', None) for d in ll]
In[7]: ld
Out[7]: ['apple', 'banana', 'cars']
```

You can do this with a combination of `map` and `lambda` as well but list comprehension looks more elegant and pythonic.

For a smaller input list comprehension is way to go but if the input is really big then i guess generators are the ideal way.

```
In[11]: gd = (d.get('value', None) for d in ll)
In[12]: gd
Out[12]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5774568b10>
In[13]: '-'.join(gd)
Out[13]: 'apple-banana-cars'
```

Here is a comparison of all possible solutions for bigger input

```
 In[2]: l = [{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3} , {'value': 'cars', 'blah':4}] * 9000000
In[3]: def gen_version():
  ...:     for i in l:
  ...:         yield i.get('value', None)
  ...: 
In[4]: def list_comp_verison():
  ...:     return [i.get('value', None) for i in l]
  ...: 
In[5]: def list_verison():
  ...:     ll = []
  ...:     for i in l:
  ...:         ll.append(i.get('value', None))
  ...:     return ll
In[10]: def map_lambda_version():
   ...:      m = map(lambda i:i.get('value', None), l)
   ...:      return m
   ...: 
In[11]: %timeit gen_version()
172 ns ± 0.393 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In[12]: %timeit map_lambda_version()
203 ns ± 2.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In[13]: %timeit list_comp_verison()
1.61 s ± 20.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In[14]: %timeit list_verison()
2.29 s ± 4.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see, generators are a better solution in comparison to the others, map is also slower compared to generator for reason I will leave up to OP to figure out.

Answer (score 6):

For a very simple case like this, a comprehension, as in [Ismail Badawi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271523/908494) is definitely the way to go.

But when things get more complicated, and you need to start writing multi-clause or nested comprehensions with complex expressions in them, it's worth looking into other alternatives. There are a few different (quasi-)standard ways to specify XPath-style searches on nested dict-and-list structures, such as JSONPath, DPath, and KVC. And there are nice libraries on PyPI for them.

Here's an example with the library named [`dpath`](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), showing how it can simplify something just a bit more complicated:

```
>>> dd = {
...     'fruits': [{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3}],
...     'vehicles': [{'value': 'cars', 'blah':4}]}

>>> {key: [{'value': d['value']} for d in value] for key, value in dd.items()}
{'fruits': [{'value': 'apple'}, {'value': 'banana'}],
 'vehicles': [{'value': 'cars'}]}

>>> dpath.util.search(dd, '*/*/value')
{'fruits': [{'value': 'apple'}, {'value': 'banana'}],
 'vehicles': [{'value': 'cars'}]}
```

Or, using [`jsonpath-ng`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/):

```
>>> [d['value'] for key, value in dd.items() for d in value]
['apple', 'banana', 'cars']
>>> [m.value for m in jsonpath_ng.parse('*.[*].value').find(dd)]
['apple', 'banana', 'cars']
```

This one may not look quite as simple at first glance, because `find` returns match objects, which include all kinds of things besides just the matched value, such as a path directly to each item. But for more complex expressions, being able to specify a path like `'*.[*].value'` instead of a comprehension clause for each `*` can make a big difference. Plus, JSONPath is a language-agnostic specification, and there are even [online testers](http://jsonpath.com/) that can be very handy for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

***Follow the example --***

```
songs = [
{"title": "happy birthday", "playcount": 4},
{"title": "AC/DC", "playcount": 2},
{"title": "Billie Jean", "playcount": 6},
{"title": "Human Touch", "playcount": 3}
]

print("===========================")
print(f'Songs --> {songs} \n')
title = list(map(lambda x : x['title'], songs))
print(f'Print Title --> {title}')

playcount = list(map(lambda x : x['playcount'], songs))
print(f'Print Playcount --> {playcount}')
print (f'Print Sorted playcount --> {sorted(playcount)}')

# Aliter -
print(sorted(list(map(lambda x: x['playcount'],songs))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Get key values from list of dictionaries in python?

1. Get key values from list of dictionaries in python?

**Ex:**

```
data = 
[{'obj1':[{'cpu_percentage':'15%','ram':3,'memory_percentage':'66%'}]},
{'obj2': [{'cpu_percentage':'0','ram':4,'memory_percentage':'35%'}]}]
```

**for d in data:**

```
  for key,value in d.items(): 

      z ={key: {'cpu_percentage': d['cpu_percentage'],'memory_percentage': d['memory_percentage']} for d in value} 
      print(z)
```

**Output:**

```
{'obj1': {'cpu_percentage': '15%', 'memory_percentage': '66%'}}
{'obj2': {'cpu_percentage': '0', 'memory_percentage': '35%'}}
```

Answer (score -4):

A very simple way to do it is:

```py
list1=['']
j=0
for i in com_list:
    if j==0:
        list1[0]=(i['value'])
    else:
        list1.append(i['value'])
    j+=1
```

Output:

> ['apple', 'banana', 'cars']

Answer (score -5):

Please try out this one.

```
d =[{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2},  {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3} , {'value': 
'cars', 'blah': 4}] 
b=d[0]['value']
c=d[1]['value']
d=d[2]['value']
new_list=[b,c,d]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
['apple', 'banana', 'cars']
```

Comment: Not only does this become intractable and unseemly for larger dictionaries, you actually overwrote dictionary d with a new variable here.