# How can I return an array of mongodb objects in pymongo (without a cursor)? Can MapReduce do this?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a db set up in mongo that I'm accessing with pymongo.

I'd like to be able to pull a small set of fields into a list of dictionaries.  So, something like what I get in the mongo shell when I type...

```
db.find({},{"variable1_of_interest":1, "variable2_of_interest":1}).limit(2).pretty()
```

I'd like a python statement like:

```
x = db.find({},{"variable1_of_interest":1, "variable2_of_interest":1})
```

where x is an array structure of some kind rather than a cursor---that is, instead of iterating, like:

```
data = []
x = db.find({},{"variable1_of_interest":1, "variable2_of_interest":1})
for i in x:
    data.append(x)
```

Is it possible that I could use MapReduce to bring this into a one-liner?  Something like

```
db.find({},{"variable1_of_interest":1, "variable2_of_interest":1}).map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "data")
```

I intend to output this dataset to R for some analysis, but I'd like concentrate the IO in Python.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need to call mapReduce, you just turn the cursor into a list like so:

```
>>> data = list(col.find({},{"a":1,"b":1,"_id":0}).limit(2))
>>> data
[{u'a': 1.0, u'b': 2.0}, {u'a': 2.0, u'b': 3.0}]
```

where col is your db.collection object.

But caution with large/huge result cause every thing is loaded into memory.

Comment: Is this a general python thing I didn't know?  list() on a cursor object forces the cursor into the values its pointing to?

Comment: it is a language thing - in JavaScript (that is at mongo shell you would do it like this: db.coll.find().toArray() - that turns a cursor into an array of results.

Comment: In case one would want only one field returned from the db, is it possible to create a list of just that field like so (eg in your example for 'a'):
>>> data
[1.0, 2.0]
?

Comment: To answer my own question, the best solution I found was this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to call mapReduce in pymongo and pass it the find query as an argument, it could be like this:

```
db.yourcollection.Map_reduce(map_function, reduce_function,query='{}')
```

About the projections I think that you would need to do them in the reduce function since query only specify the selection criteria as it says in the [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Asya's answer:
If you wanted a list of just one value in each entry as opposed to a list of objects--using a list comprehension worked for me.

I.e. if each object represents a user and the database stored their `email`, and you say wanted all the users that were 15 years old

`user_emails = [user['email'] for user in db.people.find( {'age' : 15} )]`

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict?noredirect=1&lq=1)