# How to get the data updated with pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Here is my code  :

```
results = db.products.update_many({"brandReference": idMongoToReplace}, {'$set': {'brandReference':idMongoToUse}},ReturnDocument.AFTER)
pprint(results)
```

I would like to have an array with the updated objects.
(the operations is ok in mongo, but i want to get back the object updated)

For the moment i have a :

```
<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x7f9d913ad208>
```

Comment: Looks kinda like sqlite in REPL. It's returning a cursor object to you. Have you checked to see if the database is updated?

Comment: @roganjosh the database is updated but i want the objects updated

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry.

Comment: If you're asking to see what records are updated, you have that info before you even execute your statement/query? The only question is whether your changes to the DB work or not. I'm not sure what else you want to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you extract results from the cursor, like this:

```
results = db.products.update_many({"brandReference": idMongoToReplace}, {'$set': {'brandReference':idMongoToUse}},ReturnDocument.AFTER)
for doc in results: 
    pprint(doc)
```

or turn the cursor into a list like this:

```
results = list(db.products.update_many({"brandReference": idMongoToReplace}, {'$set': {'brandReference':idMongoToUse}},ReturnDocument.AFTER))
pprint(results)
```

[How can I return an array of mongodb objects in pymongo (without a cursor)? Can MapReduce do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092884/how-can-i-return-an-array-of-mongodb-objects-in-pymongo-without-a-cursor-can)