# Getting the data updated with pymongo while pprint does not work

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have the same issue about getting the data updated with pymongo
[How to get the data updated with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677814/how-to-get-the-data-updated-with-pymongo)

But `pprint()` cannot solve my problem.

Environment: Python, MongoDB, Pymongo

I'm getting "x" as my recent update value, just like getting the "results" in previous link, that why I'm wondering the same solution isn't fit, my x is `<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x00000216021EA080>`

```
print(x)    
print(type(x))

<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x00000216021EA080>    
<class 'pymongo.results.UpdateResult'>
```

Here is the code:

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json
from pprint import pprint

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
    mydb = myclient[db]
    mycol = mydb[coll]

    return mydb, mycol

def change_db_data(myquery_json, one_or_many_bool, newvalues_json ):
    
    if one_or_many_bool == True:
        x = mycol.products.update_many(myquery_json, newvalues_json)
    else:
        x = mycol.products.update_one(myquery_json, newvalues_json)
    return x

ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)

myquery_str = input("Enter ur query: ")
update_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? (ex:1 for many , 0 for one): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")

one_or_many_bool = bool(int(update_one_or_many))

myquery_json =json.loads(myquery_str)
newvalues_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)
x = change_db_data(myquery_json, one_or_many_bool, newvalues_json)
print(x)
print(type(x))

pprint(x)
pprint(type(x))
```

The output

```
Enter the ip: localhost:27017
Enter exist DB name: (practice_10_14)-0002
Enter exist collection name: collection_new02cp
Enter ur query: { "name": { "$regex": "^R" }, "Age" : { "$gt": 50 } }
U are update one or many values? (ex:1 for many , 0 for one): 1
Enter new values: { "$set": { "name": "Old Mr.R" }}

<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x00000216021EA080>
<class 'pymongo.results.UpdateResult'>

<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x00000216021EA080>
<class 'pymongo.results.UpdateResult'>
```

My `print(x)` and `pprint(x)` print the same value, which `pprint()` isn't work.

I want it print out the modify data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the data updated with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677814/how-to-get-the-data-updated-with-pymongo)

Comment: @user20042973, I `already` include [same ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677814/how-to-get-the-data-updated-with-pymongo) in my question, and said their solution not solve my problem yet, therefore `I'm looking for other alternatives for this problem`, that what I meant

Answer (score 1):

> But `pprint()` cannot solve my problem.

The `pprint()` method is *not* the solution in [the question that you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677814/how-to-get-the-data-updated-with-pymongo). Both that question and the answer use `pprint()`, so that method is not the problem itself. Rather, the problem in that question is that they were attempting to `pprint()` the wrong thing. That's the same thing that is happening here.

The [answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679918/20042973) was to print something other than the object returned directly from the method. Currently, [PyMongo returns an `UpdateResult` object](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult) for those update methods. Python doesn't know how to print this object directly:

```
>>> print(x)
<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x7fe842511df0>
```

But you can print its properties:

```
>>> print(x.modified_count)
1
```

It also includes a `raw_result` property which might be what you are interested in:

```
>>> print(x.raw_result)
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 1, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
```

This all works the exact same with `pprint()`:

```
>>> pprint(x)
<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x7fe842511df0>
>>> pprint(x.modified_count)
1
>>> pprint(x.raw_result)
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 1, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
```

Finally, I think you may have copied the code from the other question too directly. Both of your update statements have the following:

```
... mycol.products.update ...
```

But `products` is the name of the collection from the *other* question. In that other question they are performing `db.products.update` where they are starting with the database (`db`) itself. But in your code you have already established the collection object as a variable (`mycol = mydb[coll]`). And you are attempting to use `mycol` when doing the update. So your updates should probably drop the reference to `products` and be something like:

```
... mycol.update ...
```