# To access values of array in mongodb and store it as python list

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, list, flask

I don't much about mongodb but I could able to retrieve elements but how do I store the values in array into python list variable.
It gives me object id and all other but I can't retrieve the elements of array for use
Help me through this.
let suppose good_trn consists [1,23,3344,56,6]
How could i get those values from using it for statistics

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


client=MongoClient("URL")
print(client.list_database_names())


db = client["creditscore"] 

collection = db["creditscore"] 


good_income = collection.find({"good_trn": {"$gt": 0}})
print(good_income[0])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return an array of mongodb objects in pymongo (without a cursor)? Can MapReduce do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092884/how-can-i-return-an-array-of-mongodb-objects-in-pymongo-without-a-cursor-can)

Answer (score 0):

**Well i am bit confused about your problem**
can you tell me what does it shows when your print(type(good_income))
based on the type you can look for the iteration method of that type

Comment: Suppose my mongoDb collection has good-trn=[130,140,150,160] as array values. In above i retrieved the values to good_income,the thing is that good_income is not behaving like a array or a list for my mathematical calculations in python code it's showing a error as cannot set options after executing in query

Comment: Error is cannot set task after the operations.