# How to find the maximum value of a document field with Python and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find a document in a MongoDB instance with the largest value of a particular field.

Here is the current code I have to do that:

```
document = collection.find().sort('experiment_id', -1).limit(1)

if document is None:
    # ...
else:
    return document['experiment_id']
```

I am using this query format (`find()` followed by `sort()` combined with `limit(1)` because this is supposed to be [interpreted by Mongo in a highly optimized way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections).

However, this does not work because `document` is a cursor type, therefore one cannot call `['experiment_id']` on it.

What I find slightly suprising is that `limit(1)` returns a cursor object and not a single value or `None` type.

How should I write a pymongo query which finds the largest value of the field `'experiment_id'` from a collection of documents?

It seems obvious that the following will work but it doesn't seem like a particularly good solution.

```
for document in documents:
    return document['experiment_id']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return an array of mongodb objects in pymongo (without a cursor)? Can MapReduce do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092884/how-can-i-return-an-array-of-mongodb-objects-in-pymongo-without-a-cursor-can)

Comment: @ray No it doesn't - which of the answers there do you think answers this question?

Comment: The accepted answer. The concept is using `list()` to get the result from the cursor. If that doesn't work, would you please help to put some sample json documents so we can see what we can help?

Comment: @ray I'm not sure how converting a cursor to a list helps? They are both collections of multiple objects?

Comment: Have you tried `.next()`?

Comment: @Joe It would probably be more helpful to post an answer rather than vaguely hinting at a solution with names of functions. I assume `next()` is an iterator function. But you just told me to convert to a list. What am I supposed to interpret from this?

Comment: I didn't put it in an answer because I wasn't sure, and didn't have time to test.

Comment: @Joe Fair enough - but I don't fully understand the suggestions you are making and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I was throwing it out that as something that might be relevant.  Sometimes comments like that inspire an answer from someone else.  It seems in this case I was totally off base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only one result - as a document, rather than a cursor, you could use [`find_one()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) with a `sort` criteria which behaves like it does as a param to [`find()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find), and drop the `limit` clause, since it will be ignored anyway.

> `find_one(filter=None, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> Returns a single document, or `None` if no matching document is found.

```py
document = collection.find_one({}, sort={'experiment_id': -1})

if document is None:
    # ...
else:
    return document['experiment_id']
```

Additionally, if you want just the 'experiment_id' and none of the rest, you can use a `projection` which would return a document with only the specified fields.

```py
document = collection.find_one(
    {},
    sort={'experiment_id': -1},
    projection={'_id': False, 'experiment_id': True}  # only experiment_id
)

if document:
    return document['experiment_id']
# else logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

> collection.find().sort('experiment_id', -1).limit(1)

returns a cursor.

`collection`'s `find` always returns a `cursor` (irrespective of the number of documents the `find` returns). In case there is no result document the cursor will be empty with zero documents.

You can perform many operations on a cursor, and one of them is to iterate the cursor. Using this,

```
documents = collection.find().sort('experiment_id', -1).limit(1)
document = None
for doc in documents:
    document = doc
if (document):
    print('Max experiment id', document['experiment_id'])
else:
    print('No documents in the collection')
```

References:

- [collection.find](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)
- [cursor](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor)