# Extracting values for a specific key from a list of dicts

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I would like to extract specific values from a JSON object to a dedicated list. My code looks like that:

```
url2 = 'https://pqrsiem/api/reference_data/sets/clearsky_DOMAIN?fields=data(first_seen)'
request = urllib2.Request(url2,headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)    
parsed_response = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(json.dumps(parsed_response, indent=4))
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"data": [
    {
        "first_seen": 1474468912626
    }, 
    {
        "first_seen": 1474468912694
    }, 
    {
        "first_seen": 1474468912762
    }, 
    ...
    ]
}
```

I would like to extract the values from the `"first_seen"` key and put them in a list.
How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of values from a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/getting-a-list-of-values-from-a-list-of-dicts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your json stored in parsed_response:

```
for i in range (len(parsed_response["data"])):
    print json["data"][i]["first_seen"]
```

Comment: getting this error:     print json["data"][i]["first_seen"]

TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: it works well when I typed  for i in range (len(parsed_response["data"])):
    
    
    
    print parsed_response["data"][i]["first_seen"]

Comment: for element in range parsed_response["data"]:
        print element["first_seen"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>>
>>> json_data = '{"data": [{"first_seen": 1474468912626}, {"first_seen": 1474468912694}, {"first_seen": 1474468912762}]}'
>>> parsed_response = json.loads(json_data)
>>>
>>>
>>> for element in parsed_response['data']:
...     print element['first_seen']
...
1474468912626
1474468912694
1474468912762
```

Comment: my Jason object located in this variable parsed_response which looks like this:

Comment: parsed_response = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

Comment: therefore I am getting this message:  TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Please, take a look on updated code, it's mostly the same like @jmv posted, but with a bit lower complexity.