# extract data from a complicated data structure in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract

I hava a structure of data like

```
[ {'uid': 'test_subject145', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':1, 'writing':[ ['this is exciting'],[ 'you are good' ]... ]}  ]  },
  {'uid': 'test_subject166', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':2, 'writing':[ ['he died'],[ 'go ahead' ]... ]}  ] }, ...]
```

it is a list contains many dictionaries, each have **3 pairs** 
`'uid': 'test_subject145', 'class':'?', 'data':[]`.
in the last pair **`'data'`**, the value is a list, and it contain again a dictionary which have **2 pairs** `'chunk':1, 'writing':[]`, in the pair '**writing**', its value is **a list** containing again **many lists**. 
What I want to extract is the content of all those sentence like `'this is exciting'` and `'you are good'` etc and put then into a simple list. Its final form should be **`list_final = ['this is exciting', 'you are good', 'he died',... ]`**

Comment: [python getting a list of value from list of dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python getting a list of value from list of dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict)

Answer (score 3):

Given your original list is named `input`, simply use list comprehension:

```
[elem for dic in input
      for dat in dic.get('data',())
      for writing in dat.get('writing',())
      for elem in writing]
```

You can use `.get(..,())` such that if there is no such key, it still works: if there is no such key, we return the empty tuple `()` so there are no iterations.

Based on your sample input, we get:

```
>>> input = [ {'uid': 'test_subject145', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':1, 'writing':[ ['this is exciting'],[ 'you are good' ]]}  ]  },
...       {'uid': 'test_subject166', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':2, 'writing':[ ['he died'],[ 'go ahead' ] ]}  ] }]
>>> 
>>> [elem for dic in input
...       for dat in dic.get('data',())
...       for writing in dat.get('writing',())
...       for elem in writing]
['this is exciting', 'you are good', 'he died', 'go ahead']
```

Comment: ++ for the missing key idea using `.get(..., ())`

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr

```
[str for dic in data
     for data_dict in dic['data']
     for writing_sub_list in data_dict['writing']
     for str in writing_sub_list]
```

Just go slow and do one layer at a time. Then refactor your code to make it smaller.

```
data = [{'class': '?',
         'data': [{'chunk': 1,
                   'writing': [['this is exciting'], ['you are good']]}],
         'uid': 'test_subject145'},
        {'class': '?',
         'data': [{'chunk': 2,
         'writing': [['he died'], ['go ahead']]}],
         'uid': 'test_subject166'}]

for d in data:
    print(d)
# {'class': '?', 'uid': 'test_subject145', 'data': [{'writing': [['this is exciting'], ['you are good']], 'chunk': 1}]}
# {'class': '?', 'uid': 'test_subject166', 'data': [{'writing': [['he died'], ['go ahead']], 'chunk': 2}]}

for d in data:
     data_list = d['data']
     print(data_list)
# [{'writing': [['this is exciting'], ['you are good']], 'chunk': 1}]
# [{'writing': [['he died'], ['go ahead']], 'chunk': 2}]

for d in data:
     data_list = d['data']
     for d2 in data_list:
         print(d2)
# {'writing': [['this is exciting'], ['you are good']], 'chunk': 1}
# {'writing': [['he died'], ['go ahead']], 'chunk': 2}

for d in data:
     data_list = d['data']
     for d2 in data_list:
         writing_list = d2['writing']
         print(writing_list)
# [['this is exciting'], ['you are good']]
# [['he died'], ['go ahead']]

for d in data:
     data_list = d['data']
     for d2 in data_list:
         writing_list = d2['writing']
         for writing_sub_list in writing_list:
             print(writing_sub_list)
# ['this is exciting']
# ['you are good']
# ['he died']
# ['go ahead']

for d in data:
     data_list = d['data']
     for d2 in data_list:
         writing_list = d2['writing']
         for writing_sub_list in writing_list:
             for str in writing_sub_list:
                  print(str)
# this is exciting
# you are good
# he died
# go ahead
```

Then to convert to something smaller (but hard to read), rewrite the above code like this. It should be easy to see how to go from one to the other:

```
strings = [str for d in data for d2 in d['data'] for wsl in d2['writing'] for str in wsl]
# ['this is exciting', 'you are good', 'he died', 'go ahead']
```

Then, make it pretty with better names like Willem's answer:

```
[str for dic in data
     for data_dict in dic['data']
     for writing_sub_list in data_dict['writing']
     for str in writing_sub_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

So I believe the below will work

```
lista = [ {'uid': 'test_subject145', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':1, 'writing':[ ['this is exciting'],[ 'you are good' ]... ]}  ]  },
          {'uid': 'test_subject166', 'class':'?',  'data':[  {'chunk':2, 'writing':[ ['he died'],[ 'go ahead' ]... ]}  ] }, ...]

list_of_final_products = []

for itema in lista:
  try:
    for data_item in itema['data']:
      for writa in data_item['writing']:
        for writa_itema in writa:
          list_of_final_products.append(writa)
  except:
    pass
```

This item, as referenced above, is I believe helpful in understanding - [python getting a list of value from list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict) (thank you to McGrady)

Comment: Note that the elements in writing are also lists... So are the elements in `'data':`...

Comment: Added. Thank you - I hadn't seen that

Comment: I think it is still not valid, since `itema['data']` itself is a list. So you need to iterate over that, not get a key.

Comment: I think now it is valid, although it is adviseable not to use an `except` blanket. +1.

Comment: Why not? In the above system, if a data item doesn't have 'writing' it will crash out with the error, and that is what I am protecting for. I agree your way is better...

Comment: well in this case it will not matter. But say you do something like `.append(some_function(x))` and `some_function` can raise some weird error, you do not always want to catch that (at that place). So a lot of software engineers advice to *never* catch all exceptions, only a list of explicitly stated ones.