# How can I create a new JSON object form another using Python?

Tags: python, json, cisco

I need to make a JSON object with less information than the original:

The original JSON object after I get it from the api service looks like this:

```
{
  "queryResponse": {
    "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
    "@rootUrl": "https://xxx/webacs/api/v1/data",
    "@requestUrl": "https://xxx/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPointDetails?.full=true&.firstResult=250&.maxResults=2",
    "@responseType": "listEntityInstances",
    "@count": "347",
    "@first": "250",
    "@last": "251",
    "entity": [
      {
        "@url": "https://xxx/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPointDetails/1897332",
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@dtoType": "accessPointDetailsDTO",
        "accessPointDetailsDTO": {
          "@id": "1897332",
          "@displayName": "1897332",
          "adminStatus": "ENABLE",
          "apType": "AP1140",
          "clientCount": 1,
          "clientCount_2_4GHz": 1,
          "clientCount_5GHz": 0,
          "ethernetMac": "xxx",
          "ipAddress": "xxx",
          "locationHeirarchy": "Root Area",
          "macAddress": "xxx",
          "mapLocation": "xxx",
          "model": "AIR-LAP1141N-A-K9",
          "name": "xxx",
          "serialNumber": "xxx",
          "softwareVersion": "8.0.140.0",
          "status": "CLEARED",
          "type": "UnifiedAp",
          "unifiedApInfo": {
            "instanceId": 0,
            "instanceVersion": 0,
            "apCertType": 1,
            "apGroupName": "xxx",
            "apMode": 2,
            "apStaticEnabled": 0,
            "bootVersion": "12.4.23.6",
            "capwapJoinTakenTime": 1500,
            "capwapUpTime": 52444681,
            "controllerIpAddress": "xxx",
            "controllerName": "wlc_5508",
            "contryCode": "US",
            "encryptionEnabled": false,
            "flexConnectMode": false,
            "iosVersion": "15.3(3)JA10$",
            "linkLatencyEnabled": false,
            "poeStatus": 5,
            "portNumber": 13,
            "powerInjectorState": 1,
            "preStandardState": 0,
            "primaryMwar": "xxx",
            "rogueDetectionEnabled": true,
            "sshEnabled": false,
            "statisticsTimer": 180,
            "telnetEnabled": false,
            "vlanEnabled": true,
            "vlanNativeId": 16,
            "WIPSEnabled": 0,
            "wlanVlanMappings": {
              "wlanVlanMapping": {
                "ssid": "xxx",
                "vlanId": 220,
                "wlanId": 3
              }
            }
          },
          "upTime": 2666643681
        }
      },
      {
        "@url": "https://xxx/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPointDetails/1897334",
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@dtoType": "accessPointDetailsDTO",
        "accessPointDetailsDTO": {
          "@id": "1897334",
          "@displayName": "1897334",
          "adminStatus": "ENABLE",
          "apType": "AP3500E",
          "clientCount": 8,
          "clientCount_2_4GHz": 8,
          "clientCount_5GHz": 0,
          "ethernetMac": "xxx",
          "ipAddress": "xxx",
          "locationHeirarchy": "Root Area",
          "macAddress": "xxx",
          "mapLocation": "xxx",
          "model": "AIR-CAP3501E-A-K9",
          "name": "xxx",
          "serialNumber": "xxx",
          "softwareVersion": "8.1.131.0",
          "status": "CLEARED",
          "type": "UnifiedAp",
          "unifiedApInfo": {
            "instanceId": 0,
            "instanceVersion": 0,
            "apCertType": 1,
            "apGroupName": "xxx",
            "apMode": 2,
            "apStaticEnabled": 0,
            "bootVersion": "15.3.2.4",
            "capwapJoinTakenTime": 1500,
            "capwapUpTime": 52445240,
            "controllerIpAddress": "xxx",
            "controllerName": "wlc_5520",
            "contryCode": "US",
            "encryptionEnabled": false,
            "flexConnectMode": false,
            "iosVersion": "15.3(3)JBB6$",
            "linkLatencyEnabled": false,
            "poeStatus": 5,
            "portNumber": 8,
            "powerInjectorState": 1,
            "preStandardState": 0,
            "primaryMwar": "Cisco_10:2d:ae",
            "rogueDetectionEnabled": true,
            "sshEnabled": false,
            "statisticsTimer": 180,
            "telnetEnabled": false,
            "vlanEnabled": true,
            "vlanNativeId": 21,
            "WIPSEnabled": 0,
            "wlanVlanMappings": {
              "wlanVlanMapping": {
                "ssid": "xxx",
                "vlanId": 220,
                "wlanId": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "upTime": 2399985140
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to create a new JSON object with only a few information from the above, like this:

```
"entity": [
    {
         "@id": 12345,
         "name": asdf,
         "clienCount": 5,
         "clientCount_2_4GHz": 3,
         "clientCount_5GHz": 2
    },
    {
         "@id": 12345,
         "name": asdf,
         "clienCount": 5,
         "clientCount_2_4GHz": 3,
         "clientCount_5GHz": 2
     }
]
```

If you look, the entity list is inside a dictionary in the original data.

I tried to find information about this but I only found information how to delete, or how to extract 1 data each time.

How I can do this in Python?

Regards.

Edit: A duplicate post?, if that so, instead of flagging that, can you please link to the answer because I spent several hours looking for an answer? (Not for Yuan Ji, thanks for pointing that separate resources)

Comment: As with any "how do I transform <x> file into <y> file" - load the first file into a sensible object structure, and then serialize that into the new format however you see fit. Don't try to directly convert file structures as text.

Comment: As with any Python "I have json object" question:  there's _no_ such thing as a "json object" in Python - json is a _text format_, which is converted in native data types (dicts, lists etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is just a combination of [python getting a list of value from list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict) and [Filter dict to contain only certain keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys)

By using solutions of both questions, you could achieve it:

Let's say `s` is the `dict` converted from your json data.

```
keys = ['@id', 'name', 'clientCount', 'clientCount_2_4GHz', 'clientCount_5GHz']
new_dict = {'entity': [{key: d['accessPointDetailsDTO'][key] for key in keys} for d in s['queryResponse']['entity']]}
```

Then convert `new_dict` by using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
your_json_object = json.dumps(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just use a for statement with a line for each entry, but your solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy one.

1. Convert JSON to dict
2. Create another dict
3. Select everything you need from first dict and put it to the second
4. Convert the second dict into json

Done