# Pythonic way of getting a list of IDs from a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, array-map

Assuming I have the following data structure

```
theValues = [
  { "id": "123", "name": "foo" },
  { "id": "321", "name": "bar" },
  { "id": "231", "name": "baz" }
]
```

What's the best Pythonistic way to get a list of the IDs `[123,321,231]` ?

If this were javascript, I'd probably just use filter on each element in the list with an anonymous function, but I can't seem to find a Python equivalent. I know I could do the following:

```
myList = []
for v in theValues: myList.append(v["id"])
```

Ultimately, I'd like to reduce the list of dictionaries to a comma-separated list, which I suppose I could do with a join... though that syntax still looks weird to me. Is there a better way?

```
myListIds = ",".join( myList )
```

Is that the most common way of doing it? In PHP, I could do something like:

```
$myListIds = implode(",", array_map( values, function( v ) { return v["ID"]; } ));
```

Comment: How about `[d["id"] for d in values]`? Also, the variable name `values` shadows the name of the dict method.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko thanks... I'll change that var name for clarity. It was sample data so I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
values = [
  { "id": "123", "name": "foo" },
  { "id": "321", "name": "bar" },
  { "id": "231", "name": "baz" }
]
ids = [val['id'] for val in values]
print(ids)
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271523/5774004)

Comment: I'm interested in how this works. I'm going to look up this and the more on the lambda function. thx.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It let me down the path of list comprehensions and they are amazing.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to map with Python as well, see below the example.

```
values = [
  { "id": "123", "name": "foo" },
  { "id": "321", "name": "bar" },
  { "id": "231", "name": "baz" }
]

my_list = map(lambda x: x["id"], values)

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['123', '321', '231']
```

About the comma separated list, if you would like to have a string, you can use `join` as below to obtain it:

```
print(", ".join(my_list))
```

If you would like to make it in one line of code, here is how you should do it:

```
print(", ".join(map(lambda x: x["id"], values)))
```

Output:

```
123, 321, 231
```

Comment: So could I also join using `",".join( list(map(lambda x: x["id"], values)) )` or is that too ugly?

Comment: Seems pretty simple and human readable to me.

Comment: thanks. Looks like both answers approach this from similar but different paths. Need to look more into this. ^_^

Comment: You probably don't need to cast `list()`, `", ".join(map(lambda x: x["id"], values))` should be fine.