# python map value to value instead of two key-value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have this right now

```
[{'label': 'ID', 'value': '8'}, {'label': 'Document', 'value': 'Authority Visit'}]
```

I wanted it to be

```
[{'ID':'8'},{'Document':'Authority Visit'}]
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python getting a list of value from list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/python-getting-a-list-of-value-from-list-of-dict)

Comment: Why do you want a list of single element dicts?

Comment: Going off of @StephenRauch, I think it might be more constructive to create _one_ dictionary with `'ID'` and `'Document'` as your keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate over your list and then access both `label` and `values` per item:

```
sample_dict = [
  {'label': 'ID', 'value': '8'},
  {'label': 'Document', 'value': 'Authority Visit'}
]

result = [{item['label']:item['value']} for item in sample_dict]

print(result)
```