# getting values from list of dictionaries using their key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like below:

[image]

What I want to do, is to get the distance value of each element which matches the outer key, which in this case is '500'.

`if key == 500:` Then print the distance, something like that.

Any help would be appreciated. This is not a duplicate of another post, I tried all the solutions available here, but I failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a list of values from a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/getting-a-list-of-values-from-a-list-of-dicts)

Comment: @bharatk no, it's not. i already used that but no luck. [d['500'] for d in list_of_dictionary] getting a keyError. or even with [d['distance'] for d in list_of_dictionary]

Comment: You should add a code sample that produces some actual output, and a sample of the output that you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop:

```
for e in my_list:
    if 500 in e:
        print(e[500]["distance"])
```

If you are sure the key `500` is present in all dictionaries, it will give you a list of all the distances:

```
[e[500]['distance'] for e in my_list]
```

Comment: It is not redundant... OP didn't tell if the dicts all have the key 500. And no, it will not be true if it is 5000. 500 is an integer, not a string.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis it's not redundant. if '500' is not in the dictionairy it will raise a KeyError. Dictionary keys aren't evaluated as a string on a per-key basis, so 500 will never match 5000.

Comment: @Silveris Yes, you're right, that solved my query. and stuck in another one if you can help.   I have this list  list_of_dictionary.append({test_index : {"train_index" : train_index, "distance" : distance, "class" : y_train[train_index-1]}})   what i want is to sort the list according to distance and get the 3 minimum values of a list along with the class attribute. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @krunalpatel Where is the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with list comprehension:

```
def get_distances(list_, key)
    return [obj[key]['distance'] for obj in list_ if key in obj]]

get_distances(list_, 500)
```