# How to extract multiple values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

New to Python here and just looking for a little help.  I have a list of dictionaries from a json file as follows:

```
x = [{'competition_id': 16, 'season_id': 4, 'country_name': 'Europe', 'competition_name': 'Champions League', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2018/2019'},
     {'competition_id': 16, 'season_id': 1, 'country_name': 'Europe', 'competition_name': 'Champions League', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2017/2018'},
     {'competition_id': 43, 'season_id': 3, 'country_name': 'International', 'competition_name': 'FIFA World Cup', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2018'}
     ]
```

Is there a way that I could filter this to just show me the `"competition_name"` and corresponding `"season_name"` ?

I've tried the following:

```
newList = [i["competition_name"]for i in x],[i["season_name"]for i in x]
```

Which provides the following output as a tuple:

```
(['Champions League', 'Champions League', 'FIFA World Cup'], ['2018/2019', '2017/2018', '2018'])
```

But for a long list it's still hard to read, is there a way to print the output so the key/value pairs for each item are next to each other, eg

```
(['Champions League', '2018/2019'],['Champions League','2017/2018'], ['FIFA World Cup','2018'])
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of values from a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/getting-a-list-of-values-from-a-list-of-dicts)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in x:
   newList.append([i.get('competition_name'), i.get('season_name')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You were going in the correct direction but then made mistake while creating output list.

Try this:

```
newList = [[i['competition_name'], i['season_name']] for i in x]
```

Output :

```
[['Champions League', '2018/2019'], ['Champions League', '2017/2018'], ['FIFA World Cup', '2018']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried so many combos of this and could not get it to work so I obviously did not try this one!! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the two lists, you can also use Python's [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```py
competition_names = ['Champions League', 'Champions League', 'FIFA World Cup']
season_names = ['2018/2019', '2017/2018', '2018']

competitions = list(zip(competition_names, season_names))

print(competitions)
```

This prints:

```
[('Champions League', '2018/2019'), ('Champions League', '2017/2018'), ('FIFA World Cup', '2018')]
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this method and it works, did not know about the zip function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in more steps:

```
list_competition = [i['competition_name'] for i in x]
list_season = [i['season_name'] for i in x]
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(list_competition)):
    new_list.append((list_competition[i],list_season[i]))
```

this will be your output:

```
[('Champions League', '2018/2019'), ('Champions League', '2017/2018'), ('FIFA World Cup', '2018')]
```

Comment: I just did two different lists and then combined them

Answer (score 0):

with `lambda` you can achive this as

```
x = [{'competition_id': 16, 'season_id': 4, 'country_name': 'Europe', 'competition_name': 'Champions League', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2018/2019'},
     {'competition_id': 16, 'season_id': 1, 'country_name': 'Europe', 'competition_name': 'Champions League', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2017/2018'},
     {'competition_id': 43, 'season_id': 3, 'country_name': 'International', 'competition_name': 'FIFA World Cup', 'competition_gender': 'male', 'season_name': '2018'}
     ]

result = list(map(lambda a: [a.get("competition_name"), a.get("season_name")], x))
print(result)
```

output

```
[['Champions League', '2018/2019'], ['Champions League', '2017/2018'], ['FIFA World Cup', '2018']]
```

Comment: Great,  I had the method to extract one item with lambda but that was without using .get.  This works well.  Thanks!