# extract nested elements from json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have this data set:

```
print(resp)

{'entityId': 'Vcenter-123', 
'displayName': 'testVCenter', 
'firstSeenTms': 1584129386246, 
'lastSeenTms': 1625163328453, 
'properties': {'virtualizationSupervisor': 'VMWARE_VCENTER', 'detectedName': 'testVCenter', 'vcenterHostNumber': 60, 'vcenterVmNumber': 1612, 'vcenterInfo': '[vendor: VMware, Inc., version: 6.5.0, host: testVCenter]'}, 
'tags': [], 
'managementZones': [{'id': '0001234', 'name': 'test123'}], 
'icon': {'primaryIconType': 'vcenter'}, 'fromRelationships': {'manages': [{'id': 'HYPERVISOR-123', 'type': 'HYPERVISOR'}, {'id': 'HYPERVISOR-345', 'type': 'HYPERVISOR'},{'id': 'HYPERVISOR-456', 'type': 'HYPERVISOR'}]}}
```

I need to build an array where anything type='HYPERVISOR'. For example, on this data set array needs to be like this:

```
 hypervisorsName=['HYPERVISOR-123','HYPERVISOR-345','HYPERVISOR-456']
```

this json file is type dict

I am trying this:

```
hypervisorsName=resp['fromRelationships']['manages']['id']
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes, of course. Use integers to index lists, not strings. In case you aren't aware, `resp['fromRelationships']['manages']` is a list.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Getting a list of values from a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271482/getting-a-list-of-values-from-a-list-of-dicts)

Comment: You can also use pandas json normalizer
    pd.json_normalize(resp['fromRelationships']['manages'])
    
Then you can list the column you want.
    list( pd.json_normalize(resp['fromRelationships']['manages'])['id'])

    Output: ['HYPERVISOR-123', 'HYPERVISOR-345', 'HYPERVISOR-456']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resp['fromRelationships']['manages']` is a list. You need to iterate over items in the list and get `item['id']`. You can use list comprehension like this:

```
hypervisorsName = [item.get('id')
                   for item in resp['fromRelationships']['manages']
                   if item.get('type') == 'HYPERVISOR']
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.